# Como usar o parâmetro data da função $.ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, web-service, apache-cordova

É possível enviar dois JSON ao mesmo tempo como valor do parâmetro **data** de jQuery.ajax()?

Existe alguma forma de chamar esses dois argumentos, já que preciso chamar esses dois json e mostrar na tela?

Segue o código abaixo:

```
var token = "Xke;
var jsonTipo1 = "{ tipo: 1, numPagina: 1 }";
var jsonTipo2 = "{ tipo: 2, numPagina: 1 }";

$.ajax({

    type : "POST",
    url : "https://producao-ws.talcoisa.net/api/Produto/conteudo/",
    processData : false,

    data : json, jsonTipo2,  
    success : sucesso,
    error : errar,

    beforeSend : function(xhrObj) {
        xhrObj.setRequestHeader("tokenApp", token);
        xhrObj.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

    },
});
//Ws

// Responsável por chamar metódos responsáveis pelos títulos e imagens  que vem do json

function sucesso(jsonTipo1 , jsonTipo2) {

    mostrarImagemNaTelaJsonTipo1(json);

    mostrarTituloNaTelaJsonTipo1(json);
    mostrarImagemNaTelaJsonTipo2(jsonTipo2);

}



function errar(json) {

    ToastMessage.showMessage("Fail!");
}
```

Comment: O que deveriam ser esses `jsonTipo1` e `jsonTipo2`? O segundo parâmetro do callback `success` é o `textStatus`.

Comment: tipo 1 se refere aquelas imagens e tipo 2 outras imagens, os dois fazem parte do mesmo Json. A ideia é atualizar essas imagens dentro do html.

Comment: No seu callback `sucesso` o parâmetro `jsonTipo2` vai conter o `textStatus` retornado da requisição ajax. Sua pergunta está realmente muito confusa. Tente reescrever e  dizer *exatamente* o que está dando errado e qual é o resultado esperado.

Comment: Para enviar dois JSON através da mesma requisição, você deve mesclá-los através do método [concat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat). Mas você está confundindo o que cada argumento de jQuery.ajax() representa. Leia novamente a documentação e veja que eles **não são** os seus JSON. O que você for "mostrar na tela" vai ser aquilo que a linguagem servidor enviou como saída (ex: um echo/print do PHP).

Answer (score 4):

Envie uma array com os objetos:

```
var token = "Xke;
var jsonTipo1 = "{ tipo: 1, numPagina: 1 }";
var jsonTipo2 = "{ tipo: 2, numPagina: 1 }";
var dados = [jsonTipo1, jsonTipo2]; // colocando ambos numa array

$.ajax({

    type : "POST",
    url : "https://producao-ws.talcoisa.net/api/Produto/conteudo/",
    processData : false,

    data : dados, // passando a array
    success : sucesso,
    error : errar,

    beforeSend : function(xhrObj) {
        xhrObj.setRequestHeader("tokenApp", token);
        xhrObj.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

    },
});
```

Para retornar mais de um objeto, use a mesma lógica, e no callback os dados virão sempre como o primeiro argumento:

```
function sucesso(arrayDeDados) {

}
```

Comment: Algo do tipo: function sucesso(dados) {algo.dados.jsonTipo1.Produto[1].imagemDoProduto}

Comment: Não entendi seu comentário acima

Comment: Não entendi a função sucesso(arrayDeDados);  quero chamar uma das posições do array e mostrar na tela, é possível? tentei aqui mas acredito ter feito errado.

Comment: Botei um link no Gist com o código, veja por favor. https://gist.github.com/anonymous/1f5e6796758375eb57d0

Answer (score 0):

Substitua por:

```
data : { json, jsonTipo2 },
```

Comment: Poderia pq essa alteração funciona, isso facilita para outras pessoas o entendimento, se tiver alguma referência adicione na resposta. O stackoverflow funciona diferente de um forum, veja as diferenças na [tour](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) a explicação é bem rápida.